# create Sql TransAction Method on Data.xsd

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I've added to my project a dataset item called : myDataSet.xsd
After this, I drop tables on myDataSet.xsd file. That's all okey.
What I want to do is, to build Sql Transaction's as function on
that dataset, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DataSet` is an in-memory structure - there is no direct relationship to SQL or `SqlTransaction`.

I think what you are probably referring to is performing operations on the generated `TableAdapter` instances using a SQL transaction.

It's tricky.

Sahil Malik has a reasonably complete [primer](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006/06/18/the-definitive-tableadapters--transactions-blog-post.aspx) on the subject (yes, it's really a "subject").  Essentially what it all boils down to is extending the `TableAdapter` via a partial class with a `BeginTransaction` method which opens the inner `SqlConnection` and holds it open and hands you back a `SqlTransaction` which you then use normally.  It's cumbersome, and you have to do this for every `TableAdapter`.  Alternatively, you can use `System.Transactions.TransactionScope`, but you have to jump through various hoops in order to avoid a promotion to DTC (distributed transaction).

I'd encourage you to take a look at the linked article, rather than me copying and pasting the code in here.

If you have a lot of `TableAdapters`, or in general need to combine more than one of them in a single transaction, Sahil's approach isn't going to scale too well.  In the past (when I still used `TableAdapters`) I used a method similar to [Ryan Whitaker's](http://weblogs.asp.net/ryanw/archive/2006/03/30/441529.aspx), which is basically monkey-patching; it uses Reflection for most of the heavy lifting.

Those two are kind of the definitive resources on making `TableAdapter` code transactionally-safe.  Personally, I just wouldn't use a typed `DataSet` at all any more; it's all but obsolete now that Linq to SQL and EF are around, they are much more powerful, have deferred execution, don't rely exclusively on in-memory structures, and use a Table Data Gateway + Unit of Work pattern that is very easy to get working with transactions.  In my experience, if those do not suffice, usually neither will a `DataSet` and I have to drop down to bare `SqlCommand` instances.  But if for some reason you absolutely must use a `DataSet` for data access, one of the two aforementioned methods should be what you need.

Comment: thanks mate, you have told really fine. (I meant TableAdapters)